# Cannot get json data from ajax request to display in html

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, api

I am trying to use the New York Times bestseller list API to list the current top 20 in html - I've managed to retrieve the data using ajax (I can see it using developer tools) but have got stuck trying to get it to display on the page. I don't get any error messages - nothing happens. This is my code as is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Discover Books</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>

    <div id='books'> 
    </div>


    </head>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax ({
            type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'http://api.nytimes.com/svc/books/v3/lists/hardcover-fiction?api-key=*API_KEY*',

        success: function(response){
          console.log(response);
          for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            var listing = response[i];
            $('#books').append('<h3>' + title + '</h3>');
          }
      }, 
        error: function(xhr, status, error){
          console.log(status);
          console.log(error);
      }
    });
  })
</script>

</html>
```

Any hints as to what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Does it default to the error function?

Comment: Don't put your api key in the code example. I don't know how this API works, but its generally a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`title` is undefined in you success function. You should refer to `listing.title`.

```
success: function(response){
  console.log(response);
  for(var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
    var listing = response[i];
    $('#books').append('<h3>' + listing.title + '</h3>');
  }
}
```

And looking at the API response, you need to drill down into the JSON a bit to get to the books.

```
success: function(response){
  console.log(response);
  books = response.results.books; //You may need to tinker with this
  for(var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
    var listing = books[i];
    $('#books').append('<h3>' + listing.title + '</h3>');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much that's solved the problem! I've been stuck on that for hours...

Comment: Hey, if you are paying for that api key or you are concerned with its security at all, you may want to request a new one.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to call JSON.parse(response) before using its elements?